# How can I pass Cursor to another Activity?

Tags: android

I need to pass `Cursor` object to another activity, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share you Cursor object using Application class, but it is not entertain because it is recommended not to use static reference much, So its Better to create cursor with a new query in another activity.

Comment: why it's not possible we can pass it using Application class?

Comment: That mechanism we can't say passing(use from a single instance), it merely like SingleTon(static) concept, the same thing you can do with normal activity and make the cursor as static.

Answer (score 1):

The cursor lifecycle should be handled within an activity or you risk causing a memory leak, ideally pass the URI used to query for the cursor in the intent like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the activity that answers this intent, query for the cursor using a loader and loader callbacks.

Comment: not sure from where can I get `uri`?

Comment: Its the URI you use to query for the cursor initially