# How to pass Cursor Object to next Activity using Intents

Tags: android, android-activity, android-cursor

I'm familiar with how to pass Raw Data(String, int, boolean etc) from one Activity to another Activity. But in my application, I want to pass a `Cursor` object to next Activity. I'm extending my class from the `Activity` Class.

Though I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098736/how-can-i-pass-cursor-to-another-activity). but it provides cotradictory solutions. However, as described by one of the users, one should extend `Application class` to pass cursor data. But I want to extend `Activity` class. So is there any way to pass `Cursor` data from an Activity to another Activity.

**Note-** If it helps, the fact why I want to use the cursor is, I'm `querying` data for a particular contact clicked from the list and saving it in the cursor and I want to pass the same cursor data to the next Actvity.

Comment: Indeed Application(recommended: use less static variables as much you can) class is usefull but concern with cursor it is BEST to reinitialize cursor on the next activity.

Comment: @hotveryspicy : i think if we want to share same data then it's better to share same cursor to other components instead of querying database again and again

Comment: then its better to create an Object of the same rather to keep database open and cursor too.

Comment: prosper: Dont worry, I found your answer, more than helpfull. but as @hotveryspicy suggested it is not exactly concerned with passing cursor and moreover I dont want to use Application class

Comment: @hotveryspicy: Yes good point, I've never thought that it would leave the database open and the cursor too.

Comment: @hotveryspicy : Thanks, @ Sahil you have both answers

Comment: Can you please provide an answer for how could we implement cursor sharing with an activty and how could I prevent memory leakage by not leaving cursor open for the entire application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Re-query your cursor on the destination side.
- Store the cursor data in a class which implements Parcelable.(when your cursor data is in small size).

Above both method will work perfectly, concern really coming when you dealing with Static ones.

*Remember:  To open/close cursor and database when required.*

Comment: so, as per your first approach, should I pass the uri of query and re-query it in the next activty.! I was also thinking about the same. But what about the second approach, I couldn't understand the parcelable concept.

Comment: [Parcelable](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html) makes you able to pass your object(stored data) to activity via intents.

Comment: Thanx, your blog post is quite helpfull and it seems to be a good approach to handle complex objects. Let me use it and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

your Cursor is just a reference of your requites query you executed to SQLite and passing Cursor it not good idea . Although if your data is not much sized then  you can get data from Cursor and save it in any collection and pass it as serialized form to another activity via intent .

Comment: what is _serialized form_.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj Serializable means you can write the object to bytes in a file, and re-create it back. If passing live object references were considered good, Android designers would have provided a mechanism instead of Bundles.

Comment: So, you mean I should first write the cursor result onto a file and then retrieve those results from the file in next activity. Seems to be a good approach though, but dont you think it would be quite tedious and moreover if it will work for contact results.