# Without sending calendar obj, it will work fine.. Then How to pass Calendar object from one activity to another?

Tags: serialization, android-intent, calendar, android-activity, parcelable

we can pass String as

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(); 
returnIntent.putExtra("SelectedRadio", selectedRadio);
```

But if I want to pass          Calendar object then how to pass it from one activity 
to another?

Thanks in advance.

This is my First Activity:

```
public class MyCalendar extends Activity {
public Calendar myCal;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_calendar);
    goCal= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
myCal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
goCal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent i = new Intent(MyCalendar.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("calendar", myCal);
startActivity(i);

    });     
}
```

}

This is my second Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Intent myIntent;
Calendar today = (Calendar) myIntent.getExtras().getSerializable("calendar");
...
}
```

what is my fault. Why my app closed when i click goCal button. pls help me.. I am a new one..

my logcat:

```
    01-09 18:55:50.338: W/dalvikvm(4252): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb5f41288)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycalendar/com.example.mycalendar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at com.example.mycalendar.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:44)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     ... 11 more
```

Without sending calendar obj, it will work fine.. Then How to pass Calendar object from one activity to another?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: you can pass parameters to constructor of the second activity class. I am not sure if this is the solutions. You can try.

Comment: [Parecelable](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html) Class seems the best option to me. Have a look at these posts, - [Pass Objects to Next Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037254/how-to-pass-cursor-object-to-next-activity-using-intents) - [Send Objects from one Activity to Another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/1626878).

Comment: Shouldn't be passing arguments to the constructor of a activity class, since you don't actually create the activity. You create an Intent with data, and Android creates the activtiy.

Comment: Calendar class does not extend Parecelable, but does extend Serializable

Comment: Hmm, Good to know that.:)

Comment: Without sending calendar obj, it worked fine. but i need to send a Calendar object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) implements [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) you can simply do the following:

```
Calendar cal;
<calendar initialization>
intent.putExtra("calendar", cal);
```

Then for retrieving:

```
Calendar cal;

cal = (Calendar) intent.getSerializableExtra("calendar");
```

Comment: pls check my update code.. i did as ur answer but my app closed when i click goCal button.

Comment: Use getIntent() instead of your (not initialized) myIntent object

Comment: like this..??
`Calendar today = (Calendar) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("calendar");`

same result..

Comment: 01-09 18:55:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at com.example.mycalendar.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:44). This line tells you there accurs a NullPointerException at line 44 in your MainActivity.java.  Does using getIntent() result in the same exception? Check if this is line 44.

Comment: yes.. it is..
`line 44: Calendar today = (Calendar) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("calendar");`
it means?? wat can i do..

Comment: Without sending calendar obj, it will work fine. but i need to send Calendar object.

Comment: try getIntent().getSerializableExtra("calendar"); Might be because you are using putExtra() instead of adding a Bundle to the intent (which would be what getExtras() returns).

Answer (score 4):

we know Calander implements Serializable interface so, you can send it as a extra in the intent.

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,Home.class);
                Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                i.putExtra("calobject", c);
                startActivity(i);
```

and you can get it using this code

```
 Calendar cal=(Calendar) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("calobject");
```

Here is the screenshot of debugged code it goes smoothly without any exception[image]
I hope this will help you

Comment: No need to 'serialize' the object, since it implements the Serializable interface, Android/Java does this by itself.

Comment: Without sending calendar obj, it will work fine. but i need to send Calendar object.

Comment: I have posted a code snippet with the debugged code please check that @bala